# Are $f_1 = x^2 + 1$ and $f_2 = x|x| + 1$ linearly independent on the interval $(-1, 1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The absolute value sign is just confusing me.

Comment: Please make the body of your Question a self-contained presentation of the problem to solve, not relying wholly on the title to convey it to your Readers.  Definitions are your friends, and a direct application of the definition of linear independence to your situation would provide a quick start to the solution.

Comment: wow you guys are mad anal on this site. Chill out. The question is asked very clearly as seen by the fact that four people answered it. I didn't provide additional "context" because I didn't have any solution to go on. I don't see how stating the definition of linear independence does anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more involved solution that gets around the absolute value sign.

Let $g_1(x) = 1+x^2, g_2(x) = 1-x^2$, and note that $g_1,g_2$ are polynomials.

Note that for $x \in (-1,0]$, we
have $af_1(x)+b f_2(x) = ag_1(x)+b g_2(x)= a+b + (a-b)x^2$.

If $a+b + (a-b)x^2 = 0$ for three values of $x$ (and there are certainly plenty of values in $(-1,0]$), then we must have $a+b=0, a-b = 0$, or in other words, $a=b=0$.

Comment: I actually stumbled across this after a couple others had posted their solutions. I think it might be the simplest one! I'll give u the check-mark.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are.  $f_2=\begin {cases}x^2+1 & x \ge 0 \\1-x^2& x \lt 0 \end {cases}$  If you demand that $af_1(x)+bf_2(x)$ is identically zero, for $x \ge 0$ you need $a-b=0$ and for $x \lt 0$ you need $a+b=0$.  The combination of those requires $a=b=0$

Answer (score 0):

If $af_1(x)+bf_2(x)=0$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$, then we get, with $x=0$ and $x=- \frac{1}{2}$, the equations

$a+b=0$ and $5a-3b=0$. This gives $a=b=0$

Answer (score 0):

Both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable functions.

Suppose we are given constants $a,b$ such that $af_1(x)+bf_2(x) = a(x^2+1) + b(x|x|+1) = 0$ for all $x$.

Putting $x=0$ we see $a$ and $b$ must satisfy $a+b=0.$

We will also have $a\frac{d}{dx}f_1(x) + b\frac{d}{dx}f_2(x) = 0 = a(2x) + b2\text{sign}(x)x = 0$ for all $x$.

Putting $x=-1/2$ we have $a-b=0$, from which it follows $a=b=0.$